# Google's new PlaceAutocompleteFragment and country codes

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm trying to implement city search in my app with new PlaceAutocompleteFragment. I have search with city filter and it works fantastic, but i can't get the country code (or name) of the city. Is there any ways to get the country and state of selected city?

My code looks like this:

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                    .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)
                    .build();

autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);

autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                selectCity(place);
                // want to get country and state
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can use the place ID returned to make a Place Details request to the Google Places  Web Service API, see here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering my question. My app is only client side and there's note _The Google Places API Web Service is for use in server applications_, so that might not be the option..

Comment: You can put the functionality into the client, you just need to use a server key with no security on it (i.e. no IP address for the api key).

Comment: @iqpolar do you found any solution for PlaceAutoCompleteFragment with Country filter. please let me know i have same issue.

Comment: @Guruprasad no i didn't... i guess this will need a server side implementation (Place Details request to the Google Places Web Service API).